# How can I generate all possible strings given a grammar rule?

Tags: python, context-free-grammar

I would like to, given a JSGF grammar, generate all the terminal strings it would map to. For example, given `A (B | C) D [E]`, my desired output would be:

```
A B D E
A C D E
A B D
A C D
```

I decided to start with the easiest item, the optional brackets, but soon ran into a brick wall. It sort of works for 1 item, but not for an item with alternatives. Any advice would be appreciated.

What I have now:

```
import re
rule = raw_input('Enter the rule you want to test: ')
items = re.findall(r"\w[\w ]*\w|\w|\[|\]|\(|\)", rule)
for anitem in range(len(items)):
    bracketc = items[:anitem].count('[') - items[:anitem].count(']')
    if items[anitem] != '[' and items[anitem] != ']':
        if bracketc > 0:
            optional = True
        else:
            optional = False
        while optional == True:
            print ' '.join(items)
            it2 = items[:]
            it2.remove(it2[anitem])
            print ' '.join(it2)
            break
```

It works for 1 item, and given a string A B [C] D, returns:

```
A B [ C ] D
A B [ ] D
```

but breaks down at increasing complexity, so I am guessing I need something completely different.

Comment: what about something like `A: BC | BCA` which leads to infinite potential strings

Comment: I'm not worrying about recursion right now ;) I just want to get the simplest version to work for now, assuming every item in the rule is a terminal node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I've written the following piece of code :

```
rule="A(B|C)D[E]FG"

def generate_strings(rule):
    if not rule:
        return [""]
    begin,end=rule[0],rule[1:]
    if begin=='[':
        i=end.find(']')
        if i==-1:
            raise Exception("Unmatched '['")
        alt,end=end[0:i],end[i+1:]
        return [a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in [alt,""]]
    if begin=='(':
        i=end.find(')')
        if i==-1:
            raise Exception("Unmatched '('")
        alt,end=end[0:i].split('|'),end[i+1:]
        return [a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in alt]
    if begin in [']',')','|']:
        raise Exception("Unexpected " + begin)
    return [begin + e for e in generate_strings(end)]

print generate_strings(rule)
```

**Edit :**
This is an attempt to make things work with nested expression. It doesn't quite work all the time as the parsing is much more delicate now : when we find a closing bracket, it might not be the one we want but the one for a nested expression. The same for pipes and parenthesis.

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def generate_strings(rule):
    if not rule:
        return [""]
    begin,end=rule[0],rule[1:]
    if begin=='[':
        i=end.find(']')
        if i==-1:
            raise Exception("Unmatched '['")
        alt=flatten([generate_strings(a) for a in [end[0:i],""]])
        end=end[i+1:]
        return [a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in alt]
    if begin=='(':
        i=end.find(')')
        if i==-1:
            raise Exception("Unmatched '('")
        alt=flatten([generate_strings(a) for a in end[0:i].split('|')])
        end=end[i+1:]
        return [a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in alt]
    if begin in [']',')','|']:
        raise Exception("Unexpected " + begin)
    return [begin + e for e in generate_strings(end)]

print generate_strings(rule)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is far better than anything I had in mind. It still fails at deeper levels than described in the example (e.g. ([A]B|C)D produces ['[A]BD', 'CD'], and not ['ABD', 'BD', 'CD'], but I might be able to fix that.

Comment: Can you please expand/explain what's happening in these loops? I am having a hard time following.

[a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in [alt,""]]
[a+e for e in generate_strings(end) for a in alt]
[begin + e for e in generate_strings(end)]

Comment: When we have '[A|B|C][D|E]', alt is the list of alternative strings ('A','B','C') and end is the end of the list ('[D|E]'). We generate the strings corresponding to the end ('D' and 'E') and we generate of combinaisons by concatenating  strings from alt and strings from generate_strings(end). (The same thing for conditional expression '(A)' but the corresponding list of values is '' and 'A').

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I played around with your 2nd script, and unfortunately there's an issue, it can't parse a[b|c]d. I changed a few things (notably, moving .split('|') from the alt to the sublist[0] in the flattener. With that configuration, it parses a[b|c]d as expected (abd, acd, ad); but fails at (a[b]|c), which becomes (ab, c), instead of (a, ab, c), which it is with the .split('|') down in the definition of alt. I've been struggling with this all day and can't seem to find a working workaround.

Comment: Well, the current implementation is flawed indeed. However, my feeling is that "a[b|c]d" is not a correct rule. My assumption was that (A|B) was used for alternatives and [A] for conditionals. In any case, if you want to go further, you'll need a proper parsing method. The issue here is that when parsing '[[A][B]]' for instance, it gets it as if the beginning was the element '[A' between '[' and ']'. The parsing is not subtle enough to get the corresponding matching bracket. The same applies to parenthesis and pipes.

Comment: You're right, a([b]|[c])d gets parsed correctly. Maybe it'll be easier for me to change the format of the grammar instead of the script. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Generator form of Josay's answer:

```
def generate_strings(rule):
    if not rule:
        yield ""
    else:
        begin, end = rule[0], rule[1:]
        if begin == '[':
            i = end.find(']')
            if i == -1:
                raise ValueError("Unmatched '['")
            optional, end = end[:i], end[i+1:]
            for e in generate_strings(end):
                yield e
                yield optional + e
        elif begin == '(':
            i = end.find(')')
            if i == -1:
                raise ValueError("Unmatched '('")
            parts, end = end[:i].split('|'), end[i+1:]

            for e in generate_strings(end):
                for p in parts:
                    yield p + e
        elif begin in '])|':
            raise ValueError("Unexpected " + begin)
        else:
            for e in generate_strings(end):
                yield begin + e
```

```
>>> list(generate_strings("A(B|C)D[E]FG"))
['ABDFG', 'ACDFG', 'ABDEFG', 'ACDEFG']
```

Comment: Thanks :) I changed it into a loop instead, so one can test more than one rule per run:

over = False
rule= raw_input('Enter the rule you want to test: ')
while over == False:

<Josay's code>

rule = raw_input('\n\nAgain? (rule/n) ')
if rule == 'n':
over = True