# Python help: generating all possible strings given optional character

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to write a function in Python that, given a string and an optional character, generates all possible strings from the given string. The big picture is using this function to eventually help with turning a CFG into chomsky normal form.

For example, given a string 'ASA' and optional character 'A', I want to be able to generate the following array:

```
['SA', 'AS', 'S']
```

Since these are all the possible strings that can be generated by omitting one or both of the A's of the original string.

For reference, I've looked at the following question: [generating all possible strings given a grammar rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174891/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-strings-given-a-grammar-rule), but the problem seemed to be slightly different since the rules of the grammar were defined in the original string.

Here is my thinking on how to go about solving the problem: Have a recursive function that takes a string and an optional character, loops through the string to find the first optional character, then create a new string that has the first optional character omitted, add this to a return array, and call itself again with the string it just generated and the same optional character.

Then, after all recursions return, go back to the original string and omit the second occurrence of the optional character, and repeat the process.

This would continue on until all occurrences of the optional character were omitted.

I was wondering if there was any better way of doing this than by using the type of logic I just described.

Comment: But did you try anything?

Comment: Your solution is quite efficient. As for another, you might try to "play" around `itertools` module (combination, permutations, etc): first of all, find all occurences of "optional character", then create iterator over all possible unqiue combinations of its' indexes.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to create a function similar to the one I described. I'll be sure to take a look at itertools later on once everything is up and running to see if I can make things more efficient. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments it could also be done with itertools. Here's a quick demonstration:

```
import itertools

mystr='ABCDABCDAABCD'
optional_letter='A'

indices=[i for i,char in enumerate(list(mystr)) if char==optional_letter]

def remover(combination,mystr):

    mylist=list(mystr)

    for index in combination[::-1]:
        del mylist[index]

    return ''.join(mylist)

all_strings=[remover(combination,mystr) 
             for n in xrange(len(indices)+1) 
             for combination in itertools.combinations(indices,n)]

for string in all_strings: print string
```

It first finds all indices of occurrences of your character, then removes all the combinations of these indices from your string. If you have two optional letters in a row in the sring you will get duplicates which can be removed by using:

```
set(all_strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the combinations method, that returns a list of all possible combinations (without regard to order) of elements a list. Pass a list of indexes of the occurrences of your character to it, and the rest is straightforward:

```
def indexes(string, char):
    return [i for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] == char]

def combinations(chars, max_length=None):
    if max_length is None:
        max_length = len(chars)
    if len(chars) == 0:
        return [[]]
    nck = []
    for sub_list in combinations(chars[1:], max_length):
        nck.append(sub_list)
        if len(sub_list) < max_length:
            nck.append(chars[:1] + sub_list)
    return nck

def substringsOmitting(string, char):
    subbies = []
    for combo in combinations(indexes(string, char)):
        keepChars = [string[i] for i in range(len(string)) if not i in combo]
        subbies.append(''.join(keepChars))
    return subbies

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(substringsOmitting('ASA', 'A'))

output: ['ASA', 'SA', 'AS', 'S']
```

It does contain the string itself, too. But this should be a good starting point.